# JSON-Path Combining Expression With Index

Tags: json, jsonpath

Given the following sample JSON where we will not always know the order...

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": 287997,
      "type": "P",
      "relationship": "Mother",
      "firstName": "Sara",
      "lastName": "Johnson"  
    },
    {
      "id": 300982,
      "type": "EC",
      "relationship": "Aunt",
      "firstName": "Janet",
      "lastName": "Smith"  
    },
    {
      "id": 287200,
      "type": "P",
      "relationship": "Father",
      "firstName": "William",
      "lastName": "Johnson"  
    },
    {
      "id": 287997,
      "type": "EC",
      "relationship": "Friend",
      "firstName": "Harold",
      "lastName": "Johnson"  
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to retrieve the first contact which is of type 'EC'. The following retrieves all 'EC' type contacts just fine...

```
$.contacts[?(@.type == 'EC')]
```

But, I want only the first EC contact. I tried...

```
$.contacts[?(@.type == 'EC')][0]
```

But this did not work. I tried a few other variations with no luck. I would like to be able to achieve this without going outside of the JSON-Path approach if possible.

I know I can combine expressions like this...

```
$.contacts[?(@.type == 'EC' && @.firstName == 'Janet')]
```

But, I need to get the first contact that matches the 'EC' expression. So, after the 'EC' expression is evaluated, get the first of the filtered contacts.

I appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin - yesterday I released a JS-lib I've been working on (DefiantJS) that solves your problem exactly the way you want it, and with the standardised XPath instead of JSONPath. At this page, there is a tool I've written XPath evaluator.

http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator

By clicking "Edit", I have pasted your JSON structure, and clicked "Edit" again (so that the structure is parsed by the tool). Now, entering the XPath below will filter the selection you want:

```
//contacts[./type="EC"][1]
```

To put this in Javascript code:

```
var obj = {
   "contacts": [
      {
         "id": 287997,
         "type": "P",
         "relationship": "Mother",
         "firstName": "Sara",
         "lastName": "Johnson"
      },
      {
         "id": 300982,
         "type": "EC",
         "relationship": "Aunt",
         "firstName": "Janet",
         "lastName": "Smith"
      },
      {
         "id": 287200,
         "type": "P",
         "relationship": "Father",
         "firstName": "William",
         "lastName": "Johnson"
      },
      {
         "id": 287997,
         "type": "EC",
         "relationship": "Friend",
         "firstName": "Harold",
         "lastName": "Johnson"
      }
   ]
};

var sel = JSON.search(obj, '//contacts[./type="EC"][1]');
// sel[0] will contain your filtered object
```

DefiantJS extends the global object with a new method; "search". Since the function "search" always returns an array of matching elements, the handle to your selection is "sel[0]". Another Xpath for selecting contacts with the lastName "Johnson" is:

```
//contacts[./lastName="Johnson"]
```

The XPath evaluator tool have example XPath as well - which is meant to ease in developers not familiar with XPath. The source code of DefiantJS can be found at Github:

https://github.com/hbi99/defiant.js

Comment: This looks perfect. I will give it a try in my project. Thanks!

Comment: Tired of seeing these "answers" on StackOverflow. JSONPath (as the question is tagged) is a specification, not a JS library; your promotions of defiant.js don't help JSONPath users in other languages.

Comment: Well, it is an outdated specification and not a standard. But...XPath is a standard - you really need to understand the difference. As you might see from the response, it helped Kevin and many others. What is your response contributing to?
If you do not have anything to contribute, people like you should really stop polluting the threads.